# What is the effective potential for photons in Newtonian gravity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, photons

I am confused about the movement of photons and their trajectory, I hope you can help me:

1. What kind of path does light follow in Newtonian gravity?
2. What is the effective potential for photons in Newtonian gravity?

Comment: What exactly is your confusion? In Newtonian gravity, a photon is just a particle of negligible mass and high initial velocity.

Comment: I understand that light bends as it passes through the sun. How is this phenomenon understood from Newton's gravity?

Comment: What is the equation of the trajectory for this case? Does it have something to do with the effective potential or the binet equation?

Comment: In Newtonian gravity the path of a light corpuscle passing near the Sun  is just a standard [hyperbolic trajectory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_trajectory). FWIW, the escape velocity near the Sun's surface is ~617.7 km/s or ~c/485.

Answer (score 3):

Answering your questions:

1 - To apply the Newton classical mechanics (with the maintaining of angular momentum and mechanical energy) to a photon, it must be assumed that it has a mass $ m $, even if infinitesimal.

Considering that its angular momentum is $ \neq 0 $, the path of a photon subjected to a gravitational field is a conic whose nature (hyperbola, parabola, ellipse or circle) depends on the initial conditions.

With the radial coordinate $ r $ and the phase angle $ \phi $ of the photon, the angular momentum per unit mass $ K $ and $ u={1\over r} $, the equation of the path is:
$$ u(\phi)=\frac{GM}{K^2}(1+e\cos(\phi-\phi_0)) $$
with $ G $ gravitational constant, $ M $ mass of the object generating the gravitational field, $ e $ eccentricity and $ \phi_0 $ axis of the conic.

The parameters $ e $ and $ \phi_0 $ depend on the initial conditions.

The conic will be, according to mechanical energy = $ E_{meca}={1\over 2}m(\frac{GM}{K})^2(e^2-1) $:

an hyperbola if $ E_{meca}>0\iff e>1 $,

a parabola if $ E_{meca}=0\iff e=1 $,

an ellipse if $ E_{meca}<0\iff e<1 $ (a circle if $ e=0 $).

For example, considering that the photon is coming from $ \infty $ with $ c $ speed of the light in vacuum, we have:
$ e=\sqrt{1+(\frac{cK}{GM})^2}>1 $ which means that the path is an hyperbola, with axis $ \phi_0=\arccos(-{1\over e}) $.

The speed of the photon is $ v(r)=c\sqrt{1+\frac{2GM}{c^2r}} $ which shows that in classical mechanics, the speed of the light in vacuum is not invariant.

If we consider now that the photon is coming from $ \infty $ with a speed $ v_\infty=0 $, the eccentricity $ e=\sqrt{1+(\frac{v_\infty K}{GM})^2}=1 $ with means that the path is a parabola.

[image: classical mechanics plot of the parabolic trajectory of a photon deflected by a massive object of mass M]

with norm of angular momentum per unit mass = $ \frac{2GM}{c} $.

The speed of the photon is $ v(r)=\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}} $ and its speed with respect to its phase angle $ \phi $ is as follows:

[image: classical mechanics plot of the norm of the speed of a photon deflected by a massive object of mass M, as a function of its phase angle]

with norm of angular momentum per unit mass = $ \frac{2GM}{c} $.

The speed of the photon is $ c $ for $ \phi=\pi $, that is $ r=\frac{2GM}{c^2} $.

At the end, if we consider that the photon is emitted from $ r_{em}<\frac{2GM}{c^2} $ and with a speed $ c $, $ E_{meca}={1\over 2}mc^2-\frac{GmM}{r} $ is $ <0 $ which means that the path is an ellipse.

The speed of the photon is $ v(r)=c\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r_{em}}(1-\frac{r_{em}}{r})} $

A very specific case occurs if the photon is emitted from $ r_{em}=\frac{GM}{c^2} $ perpendicularly and with a speed $ c $: the path is a circle with radius $ \frac{GM}{c^2} $, and this is the only case where classical mechanics gives for a photon an invariant speed equal to $ c $.

Furthermore, since the physical radius of the massive object is $ <r_{em} $, the hypothesis $ r_{em}<\frac{2GM}{c^2} $ means that this radius is $ <\frac{2GM}{c^2} $ which is the definition of a black hole in Schwarzschild metrics.

To complete the answer to question 1, in my opinion classical mechanics should not be applied to a photon which has no mass and classical mechanics do not reproduce actual observations regarding the deflection of light by massive objects and the constant speed of light in vacuum.

2 - The effective potential for a photon can be calculated according to general relativity. If we use the Schwarzschild metrics, with the radial coordinate $ r $ of the photon and $ R_s $ = Schwarzschild radius = $ \frac{2GM}{c^2} $, it is:

$$ U_{eff}(r)={1\over r^2}(1-\frac{R_s}{r}) $$

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

In Newton gravity the Sun accelerates all matter by GM/r, even light. The path of light is a hyperbola.